# soapui jdbc: java.sql.SQLException: Data type mismatch. (2015-02-04)

Tags: sql, jdbc, groovy, soapui

I need to use sql query to DB from soap every day automatically.
Query to DB has current date.

So, I do following:

1) I set current date to properties with groovy:

```
def dateTime= new Date()    
setProperty.setPropertyValue('currDate', String.format("%tF", dateTime, new Date()))
```

2) in jdbc request I make corresponding property, and try to use it in query:

```
select * ...
where SENDDATE = :Date
```

But trying to execute query leads to mismatching of datatypes.

```
2015-02-04 17:17:54 - Error getting response; java.sql.SQLException: Data type mismatch. (2015-02-04)
```

So, my question is: how to avoid mismatching in this case?

Note: query is working correct with '2015-02-02' direct filled date.

Dmitry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use SQL to figure out the date, and then it will always be in the correct format:

```
select * ...
where SENDDATE = now()
```

Answer (score 0):

As @SiKing suggest you can use SQL functions, only note that if you're using an sqlserver instead of `now()` you've to use `GETDATE()`:

```
select * ...
where SENDDATE = GETDATE()
```

Anyway if you want to use your parameter instead of the functions and sometimes seems that string doesn't work as date you can try to convert the string to date using format functions, since it's not clear to me what DB are you using I show you the follow cases:

**oracle**

```
select * ...
where SENDDATE = TO_DATE(:Date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

**mySql**

```
select * ...
where SENDDATE = STR_TO_DATE(:Date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

**sqlserver**

```
select * ...
where SENDDATE = CONVERT(DATETIME,:Date,20)
```

The sqlserver case is the less intuitive, 20 is the format for `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss` so I'm not really sure that you can convert `2015-02-04` maybe you've to append hh:mi:ss in your groovy as `2015-02-04 00:00:00`

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure your mysql field data type is relevant (it should be 'date' not time(), text, varchar etc.)

Regarding the groovy formatting way, Here is how:

```
import groovy.time.*
def dateTime= new Date().format('yyyy/MM/dd') 
testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Properties"].setPropertyValue('currDate',dateTime.toString())
```

**JDBC (mysql Engine) Query:**

```
select * ... 
where SENDDATE = '${Properties#currDate}'
```

**Notes:**

- The format in your db will be standard like 2015-02-05
- You can have the format like 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss' if you want to have the time as well, in that case you mysql field datatype must be 'datetime()'.